# Column aliases reference

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904

This query breaks the number into its respected place like thousands, hundreds, fifties, etc. The problem is that I am unable to refer the column by its aliases name. In Oracle, I am getting this error:

> ora-00904: "twos": invalid identifier

but the code runs well in MS Access

Query:

```
SELECT 
    BT, 
    CNO, 
    AMT,  
    TRUNC(AMT/1000) AS THS, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(THS*1000))/500) AS FIVHUN, 
    TRUNC((AMT-((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500)))/100) AS HUND, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500))+(HUND*100)))/50) AS FIF, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500))+(HUND*100)+(FIF*50)))/20) AS TWENTY, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500))+(HUND*100)+(FIF*50)+(TWENTY*20)))/10) AS TENS, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500))+(HUND*100)+(FIF*50)+(TWENTY*20)+(TENS*10)))/5) AS FIVES, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500))+(HUND*100)+(FIF*50)+(TWENTY*20)+(TENS*10)+(FIVES*5)))/2) AS TWOS, 
    TRUNC((AMT-(((THS*1000)+(FIVHUN*500))+(HUND*100)+(FIF*50)+(TWENTY*20)+(TENS*10)+(FIVES*5)+(TWOS*2)))/1) AS ONES 
FROM 
    EMPLOYER;
```

Comment: And what if you use another alias? Maybe `TWOS` is a reserved word, although I don't know it.

Comment: You can't use an alias within the same (level of) query. From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries002.htm#sthref2213): "You can use a column alias, c_alias, to label the immediately preceding expression in the select list so that the column is displayed with a new heading. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. The alias can be used in the ORDER BY clause, but not other clauses in the query". Which explains the error, but doesn't really help you...

Comment: You cannot refer to an alias in the same SELECT clause but you can do so in the group by/orderby as the alias would be column name in the worktable which is not even formed during selection.

Comment: @Vikdor - you can't use it in a `group by` either (nor, more annoyingly, `having`); only in `order by`.

Comment: I know that Enterprise SQL users despise and look down upon MS Access, but it's a pretty smart RDBMS - sometimes too smart. In addition, it's much much more than just an RDMBS. Alex Poole pretty much answered your question. However, you left people scratching their heads on what you are doing. If my guess is correct, you are breaking the amounts into available units (bills) of a local currency. This is the reason I like this site, it's a judgement free zone. But giving them this context, people could come up with much cooler solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can only refer to a column alias in an outer select, so unless you recalculate all the previous values for each column you'd need to nest each level, which is a bit ugly:

```
select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun, hund, fif, twenty, tens, fives, twos,
    trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500)-(hund*100)-(fif*50)-(twenty*20)
        -(tens*10)-(fives*5)-(twos*2))/1) as ones
from (
    select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun, hund, fif, twenty, tens, fives,
        trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500)-(hund*100)-(fif*50)-(twenty*20)
            -(tens*10)-(fives*5))/2) as twos
    from (
        select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun, hund, fif, twenty, tens,
            trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500)-(hund*100)-(fif*50)-(twenty*20)
                -(tens*10))/5) as fives
        from (
            select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun, hund, fif, twenty,
                trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500)-(hund*100)-(fif*50)
                    -(twenty*20))/10) as tens
            from (
                select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun, hund, fif,
                    trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500)-(hund*100)
                        -(fif*50))/20) as twenty
                from (
                    select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun, hund,
                        trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500)
                            -(hund*100))/50) as fif
                    from (
                        select bt, cno, amt, ths, fivhun,
                            trunc((amt-(ths*1000)-(fivhun*500))/100) as hund
                        from (
                            select bt, cno, amt, ths,
                                trunc((amt-trunc(ths*1000))/500) as fivhun
                            from (
                                select bt, cno, amt,
                                    trunc(amt/1000) as ths from employer

                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

... which gives something like:

```
 BT CNO              AMT     THS FIVHUN HUND FIF TWENTY TENS FIVES TWOS ONES
--- --- ---------------- ------- ------ ---- --- ------ ---- ----- ---- ----
  1   2      123,456,789  123456      1    2   1      1    1     1    2    0
  3   4       87,654,321   87654      0    3   0      1    0     0    0    1
  5   6        1,234,567    1234      1    0   1      0    1     1    1    0
```

---

Not that much prettier, but a recursive version, mostly for my own amusement:

```
with t as (
    select bt, cno, amt, x,
        case x when 1 then 1000 when 2 then 500 when 3 then 100
            when 4 then 50 when 5 then 20 when 6 then 10 when 7 then 5
            when 8 then 2 when 9 then 1 end as bill
    from employer
    cross join (select level as x from dual connect by level < 10)
),
r (bt, cno, amt, x, y, running) as (
    select t.bt, t.cno, t.amt, 0 as x, 0 as y, 0 as running
    from t
    where t.x = 1 -- could be any x, just want one row per bt/cno
    union all
    select t.bt, t.cno, t.amt, t.x,
        trunc((t.amt - r.running)/t.bill) as y,
        r.running + (t.bill * trunc((t.amt - r.running)/t.bill)) as running
    from t 
    join r on r.bt = t.bt and r.cno = t.cno and r.x = t.x - 1
)   
select bt, cno, amt,
    max(case when x = 1 then y else 0 end) as ths,
    max(case when x = 2 then y else 0 end) as fivhun,
    max(case when x = 3 then y else 0 end) as hund,
    max(case when x = 4 then y else 0 end) as fif,
    max(case when x = 5 then y else 0 end) as twenty,
    max(case when x = 6 then y else 0 end) as tens, 
    max(case when x = 7 then y else 0 end) as fives, 
    max(case when x = 8 then y else 0 end) as twos,  
    max(case when x = 9 then y else 0 end) as ones
from r
group by bt, cno, amt
order by bt, cno;
```

The `t` common table expression (CTE) just does a cross-join of the real data with a dummy table which generates numbers 1-9, and assigns bill denomination values (assuming Robert Co is right) to each level for later use.

The `r` CTE is recursive, which I think only works from 11gR2. The first part of the union establishes a 'running total' of what the bills add up to so far, which is zero as this is the first step in the recursion. The rest of the columns aren't used, except the dummy zero value for `x` which is used for the recursive join. The second part of the union subtracts the running total from the previous level from the `amt` at this level, finds the number of whole bills of that denomination - which is what we want to actually report - and recalculates the running total to include that figure. Each time round the loop the size of the bill decreases and the running total increases.

So this ends up with lots of rows, with the quantity of each bill as a different row; which effectively need to be pivoted to show the values under the appropriate columns. That's what the `max()` and `group by` bit at the end does.

For my dummy data it gives the same result:

```
 BT CNO              AMT     THS FIVHUN HUND FIF TWENTY TENS FIVES TWOS ONES
--- --- ---------------- ------- ------ ---- --- ------ ---- ----- ---- ----
  1   2      123,456,789  123456      1    2   1      1    1     1    2    0
  3   4       87,654,321   87654      0    3   0      1    0     0    0    1
  5   6        1,234,567    1234      1    0   1      0    1     1    1    0
```

---

Incidentally, I initially tried to simplify this with `mod()` (as AndriyM suggests) but you can't calculate each value independently:

```
select bt, cno, amt,
    floor(           amt/1000) as ths,
    floor(mod(amt, 1000)/ 500) as fivhun,
    floor(mod(amt,  500)/ 100) as hund,
    floor(mod(amt,  100)/  50) as fif,
    floor(mod(amt,   50)/  20) as twenty,
    floor(mod(amt,   20)/  10) as tens,
    floor(mod(amt,   10)/   5) as fives,
    floor(mod(amt,    5)/   2) as twos,
    floor(mod(amt,    2)/   1) as ones
from employer
order by bt, cno;

 BT CNO              AMT     THS FIVHUN HUND FIF TWENTY TENS FIVES TWOS ONES
--- --- ---------------- ------- ------ ---- --- ------ ---- ----- ---- ----
  1   2      123,456,789  123456      1    2   1      1    0     1    2    1
  3   4       87,654,321   87654      0    3   0      1    0     0    0    1
  5   6        1,234,567    1234      1    0   1      0    0     1    1    1
```

Most of the values are the same, but the `tens` are all `0` and the `ones` are all `1`. The latter is easily explained, though it's more a question of why they *shouldn't* all be `1`. If the `fives` value is `1` then the remaining amount to split becomes even, so `ones` has to be `0`. Similarly the `tens` value is not taking `fif` into account. So, there are dependencies between the values that such a simple query doesn't handle. You could tweak the problem columns to take that into account, of course, at the risk of introducing subtle mistakes.

Comment: if writing a recursive CTE for your own amusement doesn't deserve an upvote I don't know what does

Comment: @APC - one of the things I've really benefited from here is having an excuse to try things I've had no exposure to before. I'd read about recursive CTEs but never had a reason to use one; similarly I hadn't done much with analytics before trying to answer (or just understand) a question that benefited from them. Many questions have really made me think (not always successfully). So this site is at least as much a learning tool for me as it is somewhere to help others, despite not having *asked* any questions yet. That's my excuse for spending so much time here, anyway...

Comment: Thanks for showing me how over-simplistic I was with my DIVs and MODs. Wish I could vote this more than once.